# PDF Tags don't show up in tags panel or reading order

Tags: pdf, accessibility, tagging

I am tagging a small PDF (4pg), and midway through the second page the tags stopped appearing in the tags and the reading order panel after I chose the tag I wanted via TouchUp Reading Order. If I open the content panel, correct containers are created, so i see:

```
- Container <H3>Some text
 - Container <H3>Some text
  - Container <H3>Some text
   - Text: Some Text
```

Does anybody know how to get the three panels synced again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF mentioned above has some major internal errors, specifically "General Format Errors."

To find these, I ran a PDF Syntax Issue report - which provides details about the PDF in question. This PDF had ~4 pages of errors.

The conclusion was to regenerate the PDF from the source file. *(I don't have this yet so I will edit this after I get it.)*

### To run the Report

**Acrobat 9.5**- Advanced menu > Print Production > Prefllight. By default, all reports/profiles will be shown. The Syntax Report is under the PDF analysis section, or use the find. Highlight the report then click analyze.

**Acrobat X**- The Print Production is now a panel, and there is a Preflight section.